# How to recursively zip multiple folders as individual .zip files?

Tags: python, recursion, directory, zip

I have a set of folders (named *.pages), which I want to zip into their individual .zip files, e.g. "example1.pages" into "example1.pages.zip", "example2.pages" into "example2.pages.zip", etc. I also want to include the contents of the individual .pages folders.

Currently, the script zips all the .pages files into a single file with nested directories.

I'm not sure how to proceed, and I believe I'm missing something when performing the zipfile functions.

Any help will be most appreciated!

```
import os
import zipfile

start_path = "MY/DIRECTORY/HERE"

def zipdir(ziph):
    dir_count = 0
    file_count = 0
    for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(start_path):
        print('Directory: {:s}'.format(path))
        dir_count += 1

        for file in dirs:
            if file.endswith(".pages"): 
                print('\nAttempting to zip: \'{}\''.format(file))

                ziph.write(os.path.join(path, file))

                print('Done')
                file_count += 1

    print('\nProcessed {} files in {} directories.'.format(file_count,dir_count))    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile("NAME/OF/INDIVIDUAL/ZIP/FILE.zip", 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipdir(zipf)
    zipf.close()
```

Comment: If you want to operate on files why are you iterating over dirs?

Comment: If you want multiple zip files... then create them in the loop.

Comment: @pvg I want to operate on folders which have the name ".pages"

Answer (score 0):

You only open a single zip file and add everything there. If you want one zip per file, you need to create zip files in the loop as you scan the files.

```
import os
import zipfile

start_path = "MY/DIRECTORY/HERE"
start_path = '.'

def zipdir(start_path):
    dir_count = 0
    file_count = 0
    for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(start_path):
        print('Directory: {:s}'.format(path))
        dir_count += 1
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".pages"): 
                file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
                print('\nAttempting to zip: \'{}\''.format(file_path))
                with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as ziph:
                    ziph.write(file_path, file)
                print('Done')
                file_count += 1

    print('\nProcessed {} files in {} directories.'.format(file_count,dir_count))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipdir(start_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also adopt the code by @tdelaney and use shutil module as follows:

```
enter import os
import shutil

reports_path  = os.getcwd()

def zipdir(reports_path):
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(reports_path):

    for d in dirs:
        file_path = os.path.join(path, d)
        print 'Compressing ' + d  
        shutil.make_archive(d,'zip',file_path)
        print "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipdir(reports_path)
```